# how to remove n from the date string in c#

Tags: c#

how to remove n from the date string in c#
I have data of date format
sample data  -

> "17\n06\n1988"

code

```
string data = "17\n06\n1988";
data = data.Replace(@"\n","/");
```

exp op = 17/06/1988

op - 17
06
1988

Comment: Remove the `@` sign.

Comment: Are those lines breaks in that string or are they literal characters. As it's written, they are line breaks. Why would you have line breaks in a date string in the first place? Where is this data coming from?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `DateTime.ParseExact`? eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/rHcAkA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That source string contains `\n` which is not a 'backslash followed by n', but one of the many [string escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences). Specifically it is a new line, so if you output the string it would actually look like this:

```
17
06
1988
```

To fix your code, remove the `@` sign as that is making the parameter a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#verbatim-string-literals):

```
string data = "17\n06\n1988";
data = data.Replace("\n","/");
```